# Faster way to mirror a FTP site

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, ftp, mirror

I am currently using `wget -m` to mirror a remote FTP but the speed suck, what are the good alternative (command) so we can parallel to download in order to boost the speed up?

Comment: Do you have any control over the remote FTP? Or does it offer ``rsync``? That would be much more efficient depending on the data set you like to mirror.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/). It's quite a powerful ftp client that has an option for parallel downloads:

> 'mirror' can download several files in parallel (--parallel option)
>   and a single file with 'pget' (--use-pget-n option).

It's available in standard debian's repository so you should have it as well in ubuntu without using 3rd party binaries or compiling it from source.

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned by pQd lftp is a great tool for that and it's included in "all" distributions.

> `lftp -u user,pwd -e "mirror  --parallel=3 --verbose /$REMOTE_DIR /$LOCAL_DIR" $REMOTE_HOST`

You can run it several times with `time` and different values of `--parallel` to find the best value.

Comment: Worth adding here that `mirror -R` will mirror the local directory on the ftp server.